# Callback SlashApplicationCommand is missing the self and/or interaction parameters. Please double check your function definition

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, nextcord

Hello I am trying to setup cogs in my nextcord discord bot, but i get this warning/error:

```
MissingApplicationCommandParametersWarning: Callback SlashApplicationCommand ping <function Ping.ping at 0x000002D0F5288F40> is missing the self and/or interaction parameters. Please double check your function definition.
```

and I also do not get the ability to perform any slash commands in the discord server that I have the bot in.

Here is the following code:

in a moderation folder in the cogs folder I have an `__init__.py` file with the following:

```py
from nextcord.ext import commands, application_checks
import nextcord

class Ping(commands.Cog, name="Ping"):
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @nextcord.slash_command(name="ping", description="Slash command that responds with 'Hello World'")
    async def ping(self, ctx: commands.Context):

        print("Received ping")

        await ctx.send("Pong!")

def setup(bot: commands.Bot):
    bot.add_cog(Ping(bot))
```

Then in a `main.py` file I have this code:

```py
activity = nextcord.Game(name="with joe mamas balls")
intents = nextcord.Intents.all()

class Overlord(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix="!", intents=intents, activity= activity)

        for folder in os.listdir("cogs"):
            self.load_extension(f"cogs.{folder}")

    async def setup_hook(self):
        for ext in self.cogslist:
            await self.load_extension(ext)

    async def on_connect(self):
        logger.info("OVERLORD IS CONNECTED")

    async def on_ready(self):
        logger.info("OVERLORD IS READY")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    client = Overlord()
    client.run("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
```

Comment: `ctx` seems like it's usually used for `!command` style commands whereas `interaction` is for `/slash` commands. So, maybe you need to look at some [simple examples](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/interactions.html) of `nextcord` and look at the simplest use case of having a slash command; on that page there's tons of mentions of `interaction` but none of `ctx`. So, maybe in the future, it would save you time and effort to look at the documentation and examples first, before just seemingly blindly coding something without fully understanding it.